# Check if string has url using regular expression

Tags: regex, url, velocity

i want to check if a given string has a regular expression or not. I am using this

```
#if($feed.message.matches('.*https?://.*'))
     $feed.message <a href="$feed.message"></a>
#else   
   $feed.message
#end
```

so it works for following url (and i get both message and message url)

```
http://www.p4pune.com/img/Scene.jpeg
```

but not working for following url (i get only message string)

```
string before url http://www.p4pune.com/img/Scene.jpeg
```

where feed.message contains the links (give above)

Comment: Could you be specific on the intended results? In the second case, do you really need the following? `string before url http://www.p4pune.com/img/Scene.jpeg <a href="string before url http://www.p4pune.com/img/Scene.jpeg"></a>`

Answer (score 1):

By removing some characters of the beginning of your regex, it seems to work for me :

```
(http|ftp|https)://[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;/~+#-])?
```